# Haproxy postgresql with patroni

Tags: haproxy, postgresql

I try to connect to my postgresql cluster using patroni and haproxy, in haproxy stats always i have two servers "DOWN" and when i connect from my pgadmin i have this message:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

This is my haproxy.cfg file:

https://pastebin.com/iwtySNKS

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try is check your firewall rules and see if the port 8080 is being blocked on your postgres servers. Check the postgres port with the firewall as well.